# How can I get a DIV block to fill 90% of my screen?

Tags: html, css

I tried the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

   <style type="text/css">
        #outer {
            width: 90%;
            height: 90%;
            margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
            background-color: #333;
        }
        #left-content {
            height: 90%;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 2em;
        }
        #right-content {
            height: 90%;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 2em;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="outer" style="display: block">
      <div id="left-content" style="display: block">xx</div>
      <div id="right-content" style="display: block">xx</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

However the outer DIV still doesn't fill much of the screen. How can I make it so this DIV fills the 90% and just leaves a 5% border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give your `html` and `body` a height:

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Problem fixed and now have another problem. However I will mark your answer correct and post the next question as it relates to the inner divs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your document and body to 100% width/height.

```
body,html
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

As a side note, your inner div requires the use of the float attribute if you really want one on the left and one on the right. That or some pixel perfect offsets.

If you do float them, you won't be able to get away with having two 50% divs with padding or margins, padding and margins are in addition to the width/height of the div.

You might want to read up on the [css box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).